# Power BI embedding in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I want to put Power BI Embedded feature in my blogging site.

https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-developer-get-azuread-access-token/

Is there a way to create a access token with wordpress?

I've gone through in Azure portal and setup Workspace Collection, Workspace, and Subscription ID and Workspace ID are also created.  I have everything I need, but I have no idea how to put this in my Wordpress site.

Comment: You could also use Power BI's [Publish to web](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-service-publish-to-web/)? Less hassle, free, but anyone can access the report.

Comment: That's the problem. I don't want it to be public accessible for everyone.

Comment: Also note that API has been deprecated, it will be turned off in under a year.  You need to move to Power BI Premium, which has a different authentication API.

Answer (score 0):

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/power-bi-embedded/

This is the new(er) offer from Power BI Embedded.
Follow the doc there and you can easily embed wherever you want, including WordPress